# How to convert ORA_ROWSCN to SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I just want to find the date when my row was inserted. I've my ORA_ROWSCN...

How to get SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP  with ORA_ROWSCN

And also is it possible to use `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP instead of ORA_ROWSCN for row dependencies.

Because I feel using `ORA_ROWSCN` is not more reliable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore some data try this:

```
SELECT VERSIONS_STARTSCN, VERSIONS_STARTTIME,
       VERSIONS_ENDSCN, VERSIONS_ENDTIME, 
       VERSIONS_XID, VERSIONS_OPERATION,
       t.*
from your_tab versions between timestamp minvalue and maxvalue t;
```

I'd recommend to save all the data into some temporary table as you don't have much time (snapshots usually don't live for a long time in the DB)

If you're lucky you may find the data you need in the results (the date when the row was inserted).

P.S. If there were some DDL operations on the table after the insert, you won't find anything.

`SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` is a function, `ORA_ROWSCN` is a pseudocolumn. Now you're asking how to convert a pseudocolumn to a function, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No..not like that......Currently i'm using `ORA_ROWSCN` to achiece Optimistic lock. I just want to look for an alternative. I've been advised to use `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP` instead.

Is is possible??